# Retrofit parse a form action and show it in the webview

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I know how to call the web service but 
i clearly have no idea how can i parse this and put it in webview :

i'm currently using retrofit

```
@GET(TOPUP_CREDITCARD+"/{id}"+"/{amount}")
Call<BaseResponse> topUpCreditCard(@Path("id") String id, @Path("amount") String amount);
```

[image]

UPDATE: i can't parse the data, i have no idea.
the response is this :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1 path $

where i have a code like this :

```
 final Call<BaseResponse> call = client.topUpCreditCard(SharePreferences.getUserId(context),"10");
                call.enqueue(new Callback<BaseResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<BaseResponse> call, Response<BaseResponse> response) {
                        if (listener != null) {
                            listener.onProgressDismiss(response.message(), false);
                        }
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            if (response.body() != null) {
                                if (response.body().status == UriConstants.SUCCESSFULLY) {
                                 Log.d("RESPONSE:",""+response.message());
                                 //TODO ADDED LINIENT IN THE SERVICE, CHECK IF MIGHT EFFECT OTHER WS CALL
                                 listener.onResult(response.message());//    Log.d("RESPONSE:",""+response.body().message);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<BaseResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("RESPONSE:",""+t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: ask your backend developer to provide response in JSON(REST API) and not HTML

Comment: he said that i should display this in a webview / in a browser

Comment: you don't need to parse it. Load it into WebView as it is (as String)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i just directly put it in the webview?

Comment: since the response is HTML, and WebVIew is designed for HTML - yes

Comment: are you sure you are doing the correct call? Perhaps you should specify an Content-Type: application/json in your Postman. Perhaps it is a JSON

Comment: yes, the response is correct. i just need to put it in webview

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView01);        

            final String mimeType = "text/html";
            final String encoding = "UTF-8";
            String html = "your response";


            wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
```

Comment: tried this, didn't work. nothing happens with my webview after loading.